# is there a name for this type of tree traversal / data structure?

Tags: c++

I was just wondering if there was a name for the pictured tree traversal? All other forms of traversal I have seen never follow this pattern.

Comment: Looks like *preorder traversal* to me.

Comment: When is 10 visited?

Comment: what is the ordering principle here? We seem tp end up with 3 4 7 8 9 5 6 11 12.

Comment: hoew do you get 9->3, how does it know to stop at 12?

Comment: 1. 10 is never visited, i explained this in the edited portion of my post.
2. theres no ordering principle i just randomly ordered the nodes because the data is an integer.
3. it should stop after all nodes have been visited (except the children of the boxed nodes)

Answer (score 1):

Overall there are 3 types of tree traversal.

**In-Order Traversal**

In-order traversal means to *visit* the left branch, then the current node, and finally, the right branch

```
void InOrderTraversal(Node *node) {
     if (node != nullptr) {
        InOrderTraversal(node->left);
        visit(node);
        InOrderTraversal(node->right);    
     }
}
```

**Pre-Order Traversal**

Pre-order traversal visits the current node before its child nodes

```
void PreOrderTraversal(Node *node) {
     if (node != nullptr) {
        visit(node);
        PreOrderTraversal(node->left);
        PreOrderTraversal(node->right);    
     }
}
```

In pre-order traversal, the root is always the first node visited

**Post-Order Traversal**

Post-order traversal visits the current node after its child nodes

```
void PostOrderTraversal(Node *node) {
     if (node != nullptr) {
        PostOrderTraversal(node->left);
        PostOrderTraversal(node->right);    
        visit(node);
     }
}
```

In post-order traversal, the root is always the last node visited

If I read your image right, you have *post-order* traversal.

Answer (score 0):

looks like depth-first with end-recursion eliminated.

hende `9->3` and `12` as the end point.

5,10 is some special case still not adequately explained in the question.

The folks on [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com) may have a better idea.